# Magento white page on admin page

Tags: php, magento-1.5

## I'm getting white page on magento admin url, tried enabling error reporting, getting below error.

```
Array
(
    [type] => 2
    [message] => chmod(): No such file or directory
    [file] => /var/www/vhosts/domain.com/httpdocs/lib/Varien/Io/File.php
    [line] => 248
)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was happened because of missing login.phtml file, replaced the file from a working magento installation and that fixed the issue.